# Use DTrace to see stack trace of process modifying file

Tags: macos, dtrace

I'm trying to use DTrace to print the stacktrace of any code that reads or writes a file on the iOS Simulator.

I know to use `ustack`, but need help creating the DTrace script to see which process and what is the stack trace when the file is modified.

Comment: Post what you have tried so far.